# Excel:Next year period

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to get next year period based on current month and year, for example:

> - Jan 2014 - Dec 2014
> - Feb 2014 - Jan 2015
> - Mar 2014 - Feb 2015
> - Apr 2014 - Mar 2015
> - May 2014 - Apr 2015
> - Jun 2014 - May 2015
> - Jul 2014 - Jun 2015
> - Aug 2014 - Jul 2015
> - Sep 2014 - Aug 2015
> - Oct 2014 - Sep 2015
> - Nov 2014 - Oct 2015
> - Dec 2014 - Nov 2015

**Next period**

- Jan 2015 - Dec 2015
- Feb 2015 - Jan 2016

etc.

I have tried with the following formula:

`=UPPER(TEXT(NOW();"MMM")) &" "& TEXT(NOW();"YY")-1`

It works fine for **Jan 2014** but can't figure out how to get **Dec 2014**; **Feb 2014** - **Jan 2015** and so on?

Comment: Btw, I'm new bee within Excel :)

Comment: Yes, this is the year-loop. The year period should start from previous month and one year back.

Comment: Yes, this is the year-loop. The year period should start from previous month and one year back. Because the current month is January 2015 the year period is Jan 2014 - Dec 2014 and when February arrives then the period will start with January 2015 and one year back which is February 2014. As listed above :)

Comment: Jan 14 - Dec 14; Feb 14 - Jan 15 = January 2014 - December 20014; February 2014 - January 2015. Sorry my bad, I'm new here. Is't possible to edit the question? :)

Comment: The 14 refer to year 2014 and 15 refer to year 2015. Not days :)

Comment: Yes you can edit the question.  So, what you want is the end of the next year period from the input date.  Is that correct?

Comment: How ? :) Yes, exactly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need the EOMonth formula.

`=EOMONTH(NOW(),-13) +1` and `=EOMONTH(NOW(),-2) +1` should give give you JAN 2014 to DEC 2014

from the MS Excel documentation

> Microsoft Excel stores dates as sequential serial numbers so they can
>   be used in calculations. By default, January 1, 1900 is serial number
>   1, and January 1, 2008 is serial number 39448 because it is 39,448
>   days after January 1, 1900.

To get the text formatting you are after, I would suggest that you stick with formatting the cell/column as @Makyen has suggested.  Having said that this is the formula that you can use to format the text.

`=UPPER(TEXT(EOMONTH(NOW(),-13) +1, "MMM YY"))`

Comment: I get this output: 41640 and 41974

Comment: Yep, Now format it as a date.Its the serial number of the date.

Comment: Is it possible to format it in the formula? =EOMONTH(TEXT(NOW(),-13) +1;"MMM YY" ?

Comment: Yes you should be able to using `MONTH(serial_number)` and `YEAR(serial_number)` formula.

Comment: Not sure how to do that? :)

Comment: BTW the formula works excellent for my purpose. Thank you very much. I need just to format to show the first three letters of the month and the last two digits of the year. :)

Comment: @NB_Excel, Unless you *need* to work with the text, you should be working with dates as date serial numbers and using the cell formatting capabilities of Excel to format the display of the date. You can format the cell from Format->Cell->Number(tab)-> (select date). You can apply a custom format by selecting *custom* and using the same format text string you are using in the `TEXT()` function. You can select multiple cells (or a column, row, area, etc.) and apply the format.

Comment: The easiest way would be to format the Column with a custom format

Comment: I agree with @Makyen. Much better to apply the cell formatting capabilities of Excel.

Comment: I agree that the easiest way is to format the Column with a custom format, but every time I make refrence to a new cell I have to format the cell. If I do it in the formula the format wil apply in the new cell? :)

Comment: I would suggest that you highlight the entire column and apply the format.  That way as new rows are added the format automatically gets applied.

Comment: Yes,but I work with several worksheets and charts where I refer to the formula :)

Comment: Will the formatting follow the reference in a new sheet ? :)

Comment: I don't think so. not from my limited testing.

Comment: Ok. Last question; How can I get the fromatting to work in formula? I tried this but I get error: =UPPER(TEXT(EOMONTH(NOW();"MMM YY";-13) +1))

Comment: needs to be like this `=UPPER(TEXT(EOMONTH(NOW(),-13) +1, "MMM YY"))`

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much Nathan & Makyen :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the date (as a date serial number) for which you desire to find the year period is in cell A1, the following should provide the next year period starting from that day:

```
=EOMONTH(A1,11) +DAY(A1) -1
```

Examples:

```
   Input      Output
 1/18/2014   1/17/2015
 2/18/2014   2/17/2015
 3/18/2014   3/17/2015
 4/18/2014   4/17/2015
 5/18/2014   5/17/2015
 6/18/2014   6/17/2015
 7/18/2014   7/17/2015
 8/18/2014   8/17/2015
 9/18/2014   9/17/2015
10/18/2014  10/17/2015
11/18/2014  11/17/2015
12/18/2014  12/17/2015
 1/18/2015   1/17/2016
 2/18/2015   2/17/2016
 3/18/2015   3/17/2016
 4/18/2015   4/17/2016
 5/18/2015   5/17/2016
 6/18/2015   6/17/2016
 7/18/2015   7/17/2016
 8/18/2015   8/17/2016
 9/18/2015   9/17/2016
10/18/2015  10/17/2016
11/18/2015  11/17/2016
12/18/2015  12/17/2016
 1/18/2016   1/17/2017
```

If you want the year period to start from the current day:

```
=EOMONTH(NOW(),11) + DAY(NOW()) -1
```

If you want the year period to start from the first day of the current month:

```
=EOMONTH(EOMONTH(NOW(),-1) + 1,11)
```

or

```
=EOMONTH(NOW() - DAY(NOW()) + 1,11)
```

The `EOMONTH()` function:

> **EOMONTH(start_date,months)**
>
> Returns the serial number for the last day of the month that is the
> indicated number of months before or after start_date. Use EOMONTH to
> calculate maturity dates or due dates that fall on the last day of the
> month.
>
> If this function is not available, and returns the #NAME? error,
> install and load the Analysis ToolPak add-in.